# Append Changes to Existing Text of Multiline of text field set "No" after create new site from template

Tags: site-template, splist, multiline-text-field

Description:

1. i have a site, and it contains a list.
2. in that list, multiple line of text **description** field.
3. set append changes to existing text of that description field is **"Yes"**
4. now i creating site template of this site.
5. now create new site from this template.
6. in new site, **description** field set Append Changes to existing text to **"No"** instead of **"Yes"**

why it happens ?
or
Any Solutions ?

Thanks.